# Bash pass date variable as string

Tags: bash, date, variables, scripting, command-substitution

I have a script which creates another script when run like this:

```sh
cat > "$installpath""tweets.sh" << ENDOFFILE
#!/bin/bash
source "$installpath"config.sh
cd \$webdir
/usr/local/bin/twint -s "\$search" --limit \$scrapelimit -o \$csvname --csv --database \$dbfile -ho
FILE=\$csvname
NAME=\${FILE%.*}
EXT=\${FILE#*.}
DATE=`\date +%d-%m-%Y-%H-%M`
NEWFILE=\${NAME}_\${DATE}.\${EXT}
echo \$NEWFILE
mv \$csvname \$NEWFILE
export NEWFILE
export DATE
ENDOFFILE
```

However, the script interprets the

```
DATE=`\date +%d-%m-%Y-%H-%M`
```

and changes it to

```
DATE=28-09-2019-15-49
```

I have tried escaping the variables in every possible way but nothing seems to work. Any ideas?

Comment: @Cyrus I have updated the question to include the full thing. Tanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to use:

```
DATE=\$(date +%d-%m-%Y-%H-%M)
```